# How to not contain Title-Name in table-of-contents at the sidebar of the document? (Berkeley theme)

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

So, Im having a presentation in 2 days. And since the Title and my name are super lengthy, It appears super bad on the presentation. Is there a way to avoid it?

Here is the required theme made in Overleaf

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{D:\reree\grade\kaza\riemann}}
 \begin{document}
\author{Βασίλης Μπισκετζής}  
%Information to be included in the title page:

\title{Αυτόμοιοι Πιδακες σχετιζόμενοι με εκλάμψεις ακτίνων γ}

\graphicspath{{D:\reree\grade\kaza\riemann}}
%institute{ΕΚΠΑ: Τμημα Φυσικης}
\date{06/2019}

 \begin{frame}{Περιεχόμενα}
\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}
\section{Εισαγωγή}
1234
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Did you consider to simply use another theme?

Comment: Did you solve your issue? How?

Answer (score 1):

Since the outer theme sidebar that is used by the theme Berkley inserts the short  versions of author and title, you can simply leave them blank:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\begin{document}
\author[]{Βασίλης Μπισκετζής}  
\title[]{Αυτόμοιοι Πιδακες σχετιζόμενοι με εκλάμψεις ακτίνων γ}
\date{06/2019}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Περιεχόμενα}
\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\section{Εισαγωγή}
1234
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As one can see from the above screenshot, the is still some space reserved for the title and author information. If you want the heading of the first section to appear without the vertical space befor it, you can redefine the beamer sidebar as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\makeatletter
  \setbeamertemplate{sidebar \beamer@sidebarside}
  {
    \insertverticalnavigation{\beamer@sidebarwidth}%
    \vfill
    \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
    \else%
      \usebeamercolor{normal text}%
      \llap{\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}\hskip0.1cm}%
      \vskip2pt%
    \fi%
  }%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\author{Βασίλης Μπισκετζής}  
\title{Αυτόμοιοι Πιδακες σχετιζόμενοι με εκλάμψεις ακτίνων γ}
\date{06/2019}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Περιεχόμενα}
\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\section{Εισαγωγή}
1234
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```