# Remove short title and author from the sidebar

Tags: beamer

For my presentation, I am using Hannover theme. However, I'd like to change the contents of the sidebar. By default, the sidebar shows "short author" and short title in the upper left area. I would like to remove them, keeping in the sidebar only the sections and subsections titles.

Does anybody know how to do it?

This is the code I have:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}%blackandwhite
\usepackage[spanish,portuguese,english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}%gráficas
\usepackage{graphics}%gráficas
\usepackage{hyperref}%hypervinculo
%\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{beamerprosper}
\usepackage{multicol}%varias columnas
\newtheorem*{ejem}{Ejemplo} 
\newtheorem*{prop}{Proposición}
\newtheorem*{teor}{Teorema}
\newtheorem*{defin}{Definición}
\newtheorem*{lema}{Lema}
\newtheorem*{algoritmo}{Algoritmo}
\newtheorem*{cor}{Corolario}

 \mode<presentation> {
  \usetheme{Hannover}
  \usefonttheme{serif}
  \usecolortheme{beaver}
}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}
%\logo{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{img.eps}}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[ams style]

\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=blue}

%EDITION OF INFOLINES

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.75ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%\insertsubsection\hspace*{2ex} esta linea sin el % produce la franja roja arriba
        \end{beamercolorbox}}
    }
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{
        \leavevmode%
        \hbox{%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
                \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
                \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshortinstitute
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
                \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
                \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
            \end{beamercolorbox}}%
            \vskip0pt%
        }
        \makeatother


%EDITION OF  SECCIONES Y SUBSECIONES IN THE SIDEBAR
\setbeamercolor{section in sidebar}{fg=black!90, bg=white}%color-sombra barra lateral
%\setbeamerfont{section in sidebar}{series=\bfseries}%letra barra lateral
\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{bg=gray!90}%color del fondo de la barra lateral
\setbeamerfont{sidebar}{family=\rmfamily\selectfont}
%\setbeamerfont{section in sidebar}{size=\fontsize{2}{4}\selectfont}
%\setbeamerfont{subsection in sidebar}{size=\fontsize{2}{4}\selectfont}
%\setbeamerfont{subsubsection in sidebar}{size=\fontsize{2}{4}\selectfont}
%\setbeamercolor{section in sidebar}{bg=white,fg=black!80}
%\setbeamercolor{subsection in sidebar}{bg=white,fg=black!50}

   \usefonttheme{serif}
   \useoutertheme{infolines}% numera las diapositivas
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\footnotesize\usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}}

\title[\textsc{aaa }]{\textrm{AAAAAAA}} 
\author[\textsc{}bb]{\textsc{BBBBBS}}   
\institute[]{ \textrm{uuul \\ UUUUU}\\ \vspace{0.3cm}}
\date{}

%\AtBeginSection[]{\frame{\frametitle{Index}\tableofcontents[current]}}

\begin{document}
%\bibliographystyle{amsplain}%Estilo de bibliografia
\frame{\titlepage}
%\part{Talk}
%\frame{\frametitle{Index}\tableofcontents[part=1]}

\section{}
% Slide 1 
\begin{frame}{Contents} 
    \begin{enumerate}[<+->]
        \item A
        \item Ac
    \end{enumerate}

\pause 

\end{frame}
\part{Talk}
\section{Overview}
%Slide 2 
\begin{frame}{Overview}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
    asbdf
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't shout like this. Don't write the title of your question in uppercase. And add a small complete example showing what you are  doing.

Comment: (1) always a good idea to provide a full (but minimal) example of he code you use, then we have a better undetstanding of what you are doing. (2) Please don't write in pure capitals.

Comment: Probably the following is also useful here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/498713/134144

Comment: Do you need the `\shortauthor` for something else ?